# Getting java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException from Files.move in Batch app

Tags: java, nio, nosuchfileexception

**Background**

This is a multi-threaded batch application, each thread has it's own file. I have logic elsewhere that will stop the file rename from happening in the case of a file creation failure.

This process runs as a daemon and generates a few thousand files each day. This exception happens for maybe 1 file per 3 days, so the method we are using works most of the time.

The machine running the batch is `Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.7 (Santiago)`

Java version is 1.8.0_162

The temp filenames are generated by appending the result of UUID.randomUUID() from java.util.UUID.

The real filename may have duplicates, that's why we used a rand UUID instead of .tmp for a temp file name. This shouldn't be an issue since the move portion is in a synchronized block.

**Exception**:

```
2018-07-26 15:06:01,743 ERROR (ProcessRecordsTask.java:renameFileAfterProcess():674)  - Error: Unable to rename file:
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /logs/apps/appname/FILNAMESTUFF_07_26_2018_15_05_51.xml.5c80331c-3b7e-4e16-90d7-c0d7810451c5 -> /logs/apps/appname/FILNAMESTUFF_07_26_2018_15_05_51.xml
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:86)
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixCopyFile.move(UnixCopyFile.java:396)
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.move(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:262)
        at java.nio.file.Files.move(Files.java:1395)
        at com.filetransferbatch.task.ProcessRecordsTask.renameFileAfterProcess(ProcessRecordsTask.java:664)
        at com.filetransferbatch.task.ProcessRecordsTask.saveFileData(ProcessRecordsTask.java:349)
        at com.filetransferbatch.task.ProcessRecordsTask.xmlTransfer(ProcessRecordsTask.java:244)
        at com.filetransferbatch.task.ProcessRecordsTask.call(ProcessRecordsTask.java:162)
        at com.filetransferbatch.task.ProcessRecordsTask.call(ProcessRecordsTask.java:62)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I am getting the exception from the following snippet:

```
private boolean renameFileAfterProcess(String tmpFileName) {
    boolean fileRenamed = false;

    try {
        if (null != tmpFileName && (!("".equals(tmpFileName)))) {
            Path tmpFilePath = Paths.get(tmpFileName);
            logger.info("tmpFilePath:" + tmpFilePath + ":Renamed Filepath: " + realFilePath);
            Path realFile = Paths.get(realFilePath);
            synchronized (this) {
                logger.info("File " + tmpFilePath + " exists: " + Files.exists(tmpFilePath));
                Files.move( tmpFilePath,
                            realFile,
                            StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING,
                            StandardCopyOption.ATOMIC_MOVE);
                logger.info(tmpFileName + ":File was successfully renamed to :" + realFilePath);
                fileRenamed = true;
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        fileRenamed = false;
        logger.error("Error: Unable to rename file:", e);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Error :", e);
    }

    return fileRenamed;
}
```

The file is created this way

```
private boolean createFile(String fileName, byte[] fileDataMerged) {
    boolean fileCreated = false;
    if (fileName.trim().length() != 0) {
        try {
            Path createdFilePath = Files.write( Paths.get(tmpFilePath),
                                                fileDataMerged,
                                                StandardOpenOption.SYNC,
                                                StandardOpenOption.CREATE,
                                                StandardOpenOption.WRITE);
            if (createdFilePath != null) {
                fileCreated = Files.exists(createdFilePath);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error("Error writing temp file: ", e);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Error writing temp file: ", e);
        }
    }
    return fileCreated;
}
```

The only thing I can think of to fix this is possibly sleep the thread for a few milliseconds, in case it's a file system level problem. The issue is, it's really difficult to reproduce the exception in the non prod env.

I have a suspicion that the exception happens when nearly all the threads have the same real file name, so there is a bunch renames to the same file name, but I can't be sure of this.

Thanks

**Edit: **

We had a skybot job running that was grabbing files with a. csv extension that were older than a day. I think the job was locking all the files in the folder as it was looking for files to move. After I made a code fix that allowed me to remove the skybot job, the issue went away.

Answer (score 1):

Before `Files.move` run `Files.createDirectories` like in example :

```
Files.createDirectories(Paths.get("pathTo"));
Files.move(Paths.get("pathFrom"), Paths.get("pathTo"));
```